# update List of users in web services

Tags: java, wsdl

I am trying to update a TextArea with a userList whenever a client enters as an admin. However the first client has only his name and the second has his name with the first client. What I want is to be able to update the list for the first client. For example, if a third client joined in, it should update the list for the first and second clients.

Here is my webservice method

```
public String getuserList ()
   {
       String usname = "";

       synchronized(username)
       {

           for (int i = 0; i < username.size(); i++)
           {
               usname =  usname + "\n" + username.get(i);

           }

           return usname;

       }
   }
```

any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From an API design standpoint, I would expect a `getUserList` to return a `List` than a String. For all other purposes, your implementation looks just OK.

You may consider using `StringBuilder` to build the final string than the `+` operator.

*EDIT :* to show an example scenario.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String s : username)
{
    sb.append(s);
    sb.append("\n");
}
return sb.toString();
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I an not able to use the StringBuilder could you tell me how it is applied ?